# Background pattern issue on a fullscreen slideshow

Tags: jquery, z-index, slideshow, fullscreen

I would like to add a png overlay to the body tag on this fullscreen slideshow: [demo page](http://www.loop-branding.com/DPM2/)

but I cant get this to work out. I add a class "raster" to the body except when the first image is loaded.

```
if(photoObject.image == "home.jpg" ) {
    $("body").removeClass("raster");
    }
    else {
        $("body").addClass("raster");
    }
```

The problem is that even if i set an high z-index the raster.png doesn't appear.

Any guess?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set a `z-index` on the `body`, it needs to be a block element. Try creating a div for the raster.

```
<div id="raster"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#raster {
    display: none;
    background: url(../images/raster2.png) repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Then instead of adding the class to the body, display/hide the div.

```
if(photoObject.image == "home.jpg" ) {
    $('#raster').hide();
} else {
    $('#raster').show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should create a div, to act as the overlay
the HTML for the body:

```
<body>
<img class="ac_bgimage" alt="Background" src="img/default.jpg" style="width: 1600px; height: 1062.29px; left: 0px; top: -310.643px; display: inline;">
<div class="ac_overlay"></div>
<div class="ac_loading" style="display: none;"></div>
</body>
```

the css for the div will be:

```
.ac_overlay {
background: url("img/pattern.png") repeat scroll left top transparent;
height: 100%;
left: 0;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```

enjoy :D

Answer (score 0):

Another solution can be hide the divs over the body and make them appear when it's necessary.